# In Cypress.io is there anyway to control the test run?

Tags: javascript, cypress

My 'example-spec.js' tests under the integration folder contain 15 tests, each time the Cypress.io will run all the 15 tests written in the 'example-spec.js'. I would like to choose and specify 'which' test needs to run, maybe 1 or 2 test at a time. The reason maybe I don't want to wait to see the output of all test while adding a 'new' test. Is there any way to control the test run in Cypress.io?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cypress: run only one test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55054337/cypress-run-only-one-test)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't know if there's a way to do it from the user interface, but you can use mocha methods to run only chosen tests by:

1. Replacing `it` with `xit` tests you want to omit
2. Using `it.skip` on tests you want to omit
3. Using `it.only` on single test you want to run

To skip entire context/describe suite use `context.skip()` or `describe.skip()` which are identical.

Comment: Awesome!, this is working. I too haven't seen any other option to disable the test from UI

Comment: How the same will be achieved in Cucumber Cypress?

Comment: also, for whole `describe` block, `xdescribe` worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Use `it.only()` and `it.skip()`

See cypress documentation: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests.html#Excluding-and-Including-Tests

Answer (score -1):

I just tried this `it.skip` and that didn't work for me.

But using `this.skip();` is working a lot better.

```
it('test page', function () {
    // skip this test for now
    this.skip();
    cy.visit('http://example.com/')
    cy.contains('test page').click()
    cy.url()
        .should('include', '/test-page/')
})
```