# How do I run a single test in cypress picking it by name?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm using cypress in a project of mine. I have the constraint to keeping all the tests in one single file. To run just one test now I'm editing the source code adding the keyword [only](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests#Excluding-and-Including-Tests) to the test I want to run and the I re-run my CLI command. Is it possible to run a single test from command line picking it by name ? I'm doing that in my [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42827054/how-do-i-run-a-single-test-using-jest) test and I'm wondering if it is possible also for cypress.

Comment: Did you read e.g. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#cypress-run-spec-lt-spec-gt?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cypress: run only one test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55054337/cypress-run-only-one-test)

Comment: No, I need to run a test without specify the filename. It is a corner case I need to manage.

Comment: I think that @lucataglia here is asking if he can run a test from a group of tests by giving the name to the CLI. IMHO it's not a bad feature, and for sure NOT a bad question!

Comment: In general it's helpful to include the context and constraints you're operating with in the question, but fundamentally the Cypress docs (CLI docs above and e.g. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests) lay out the options available to you.

Comment: You're right, I edited the question adding more context. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: If the answer to my question is "no, with cypress you cant'" we should have that also as response rather that just a comment.

Comment: _"I have the constraint to keeping all the tests in one single file"_ - why?

Comment: Because of the deploy pipeline I have.

Comment: What deploy pipeline? Why does _that_ limit you in this way? I'd suggest you do a 5 whys, and [edit] to include the _last_ one. "No" isn't a useful answer, but with enough context it's possible someone could tell you how you _could_ achieve your goal. It would also help to clarify the _problem_ with `.only` (e.g. if it's because it can accidentally be left in the codebase, maybe a linting rule would solve the underlying issue?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for this library https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-grep

```
$ npx cypress run --env grep=hello
cypress-grep: tests with "hello" in their names
```

Comment: As of today only supports up to cypress 10.0.0. Would be handy if it worked with versions after (13.x now)  instead of 10 or before.

Comment: Hello, Tim! You can try this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cypress/grep

Comment: thx! Now working with 10.x and later instead of 13, awesome.