# Limiting run to only one file does not work

Tags: npm, cypress

I just installed Cypress and was test running it.

Running `npm run cy-run` will run all test files which takes quite a lot of time and can become confusing.

Note that I have not added a single test of mine. The tests are the default examples coming from Cypress installation.

When attempting to limit to a single file I found several sources - including [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55054337/cypress-run-only-one-test/55054363#55054363) - that all seem to agree that the following would limit the run to just one single file:

```
npm run cy-run --spec cypress/integration/2-advanced-examples/viewport.spec.js
```

But Cypress does not care and goes on to pick up all tests and run them:

[image]

Comment: Look at how Cypress is actually being called. You're missing `--`, this is general NPM usage not specific to this.

Comment: Hmm, not sure where the `--` is coming from but it works. Please post a proper answer with explanation and I will accept it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending command line arguments to npm script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script)

Comment: I am still confused, but at a much higher level:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to run this from the command line, rather just - while writing and running your tests - prefix the `only` chain to it.

Example, change this:

```
it("should do stuff", () => ...);
```

to this:

```
it.only("should do stuff", () => ...);
```

You can add this to `describe.only` as well if you want to run a whole suite - or in your case, file - alone.

**Another Option:**

If you'd like to only run tests that you've written, you can either just remove all those example files or change `describe` to `xdescribe` or `it` to `xit` and cypress will skip running those specified tests.

**Command Line Solution:**

You're missing `--`, add that in and it should work as per your solution.

It should be written like this:

```
npm run cy-run -- --spec cypress/integration/2-advanced-examples/viewport.spec.js
```