# Run a specific function in cypress

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I want to run a certain function in cypress , even though they're all in the same file
for example I have the below functions and want to run the create project one not all of them

or do they have to be in separate files

```
it('Create Project', ()=>{}
it('Create Customer', ()=>{}
it('Create Property', ()=>{}
it('Create Object', ()=>{}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to be able to run only one test at a time.
You can achieve this by using the .only function.

```
it.only('Create Project', ()=>{})
it('Create Customer', ()=>{})
it('Create Property', ()=>{})
it('Create Object', ()=>{})
```

see a better answer here: [Cypress: run only one test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55054337/cypress-run-only-one-test)

check cypress documentation here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests#Excluding-and-Including-Tests